# How to keep the datalabels in place for 3D draggable column highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I have a 3D draggable column highchart and when I drag the chart the datalabels move all over the place. Is there a way to keep them attached to the top of their bar ?

```
     $(function() {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      margin: 100,
      type: 'column',
      options3d: {
        enabled: true,
        alpha: 10,
        beta: 30,
        depth: 250,
        viewDistance: 5
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        grouping: false,
        groupZPadding: 40,
        depth: 25
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Reading',
      stack: 1,
      data: [
        [6]
      ],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }, {
       ....other series data.....
    }]
  });
```

[JS Fiddle Sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/AjayROjha/2ty5ex58/6/)

Comment: I have reported this issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4834